# function when datepicker is onclose

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have this initialization code:

```
$(document).ready(init);

function init() {
var currentDate = new Date();
currentDate.setHours(currentDate.getHours() + 1);
var dat = (currentDate.getDate()+"/"+(currentDate.getMonth()+1)+"/"+currentDate.getYear());
  $('input[name=category]').click(loadList);

      $('#datepicker').datepicker({  
        inline: true,  
        showOtherMonths: true,  
        dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],  
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
      });

    var currentDate = new Date();
    currentDate.setHours(currentDate.getHours() + 1);

    $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", currentDate); 

    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
     onClose: function() { 
        alert("wow");
        loadList;
      }
    });


  loadList();  

}
```

The category part (line 5) is working perfectly and on each click it responds successfully.

I want to get the same reaction, but instead of "click" such as in `name=category`,  when datepicker is close.
I want it to raise an alert with "wow" and to call the javascript function "loadList" (such as line 5 does).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass a function as `onClose` in the options object used when constructing the datepicker:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({  
    inline: true,  
    showOtherMonths: true,  
    dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],  
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    onClose: function () {
        alert('wow');
        loadList();
    }
});
```